# Nodejs https request for oauth2 token (google, facebook) produce error 'socket hang up'

Tags: oauth, node.js, oauth-2.0

I'm developing nodejs oauth2 npm module: https://github.com/lexer/node-oauth2

When Im trying to make https request to google or facebook i get:

```
node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
Error: socket hang up
    at Socket.<anonymous> (http.js:1272:45)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:64:17)
    at Array.<anonymous> (net.js:825:12)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:126:26)
```

You can reproduce bug in express sample application that i've made:

https://github.com/lexer/node-oauth2/tree/master/examples/express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have fixed the issue. Instead of http.ClientRequest with secure option "true" im using https.request method now.

Comment: Can you add an example of that? what is "https.request"?